# SQL: date и time или datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, оптимизация, поисковая-оптимизация

Добрый день. Появился вопрос, у меня есть таблица в MySQL в которой каждый час будет записываться данные с датчиков (датчиков более 500 штук). К каждой записи будет дописываться время снятия данных, и тут появляется вопрос, как лучше построить данную таблицу.

Вот как выглядит таблица на данный момент:

```
| id INT(11) | value FLOAT | date DATE | time TIME |
```

Лучше использовать 2 колонки, для даты и времени отдельные колонки, или 1 колонку datetime. В каком варианте производительность при `SELECT` будет выше, если будем брать данные за день, неделю или месяц. И какими манипуляциями можно еще улучшить оптимизацию?

Comment: 1 колонку. с 2 работать же невозможно, всякие проверки на больше-меньше превращаются в ад.

Comment: @Mike, данные нужны будут в промежутке: данные за последние 24 часа, данные за неделю, данные за месяц. Чет мне кажется что все-таки лучше `datetime`

Comment: о чем я собственно и сказал

Comment: о, у меня тут в хобби проекте та же ситуация. 9 датчиков температуры в городе, раз в минуту сыпят данные в базу.  выборки обычно типа "показать за сутки/двое", текущее, архив за день. разнесено на 3 таблицы. мемори-таблица для текущих, краткая история за последние несколько суток  еще в одной таблице с интервалами по 5 минут, и таблица с архивом. пока что на 1.1 млн записей. по двум столбца работать нереально будет.  падение скорости заметно при выборке по минутам кратным 5. но пока что не критично.

Comment: @teran, а индексы использовал в таблицах?

Comment: @RuslanMelnichenko ну а как без  них. ид_датчика + дата_время. надо по изучать еще с кратными минутами. данные то пишутся каждую минуту, но на графики выводятся с интервалом 5 минут. простая выборка с архива (датчик за сутки по минутам)  0.15сек, а если добавить `minute(adate)%5=0` то падает до 0.4. возможно стоит подумать как и это проиндексировать, вычисляемый столбец какой мб